# How to correctly use invoke_result_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am having an issue with type traits that I don't understand, I have created the below minimal example. Why does the second call to `foo` not compile? It gives the error:

```
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/exception:148,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/ios:39,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from invoke_result_test.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> using invoke_result_t = typename std::invoke_result::type [with _Fn = main()::<lambda(bool&)>; _Args = {bool}]':
invoke_result_test.cpp:6:11:   required from here
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/type_traits:2957:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<main()::<lambda(bool&)>, bool>'
 2957 |     using invoke_result_t = typename invoke_result<_Fn, _Args...>::type;
```

Reading around it looks like that the function is not callable so invoke_result has no `type` to return. I would like to be able to call foo with references so I can return values and non-references but cant work this out. Is this possible? I assume so as STL code manages this. What have I not understood?

Minimal Code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F, 
          typename... A, 
          typename R = std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<A>...>>
R foo(const F& aF, const A& ...aA)

{
    return aF(aA...);
}

int main()
{
    bool positive = true;
    std::cout << foo([](bool flag) -> int
                        {
                            if (flag) return 1;
                            return -1;
                        },
                        positive);
                        
    std::cout << foo([](bool& flag) -> int
                        {
                            flag = !flag;
                            if (flag) return 1;
                            return -1;
                        },
                        positive);
                        
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the function is not invocable with the given arguments.

`std::invoke_result` automatically adds `&&` to argument types, unless they already have `&`. Your function is not invocable with a `bool &&` argument.

Even ignoring `invoke_result`, this couldn't work because `foo` receives parameters by const references.

---

You need perfect forwarding for such wrappers:

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
decltype(auto) foo(F &&f, A &&... a)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a)...);
}
```

Here, the return type can be manually specified as `std::invoke_result_t<F, A...>`.

But then for consistency you should also replace the manual `f` call with `std::invoke` (to support calling things like pointers-to-members).

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
std::invoke_result_t<F, A...> foo(F &&f, A &&... a)
{
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<A>(a)...);
}
```

Comment: can't we have just `decltype(f(a...))`?

Comment: @Const You need `decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a)...))`, but yes, you can. This also must be in a trailing-return-type, otherwise you can't decltype on arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this did indeed fix it for me.

Comment: @GrumpyBloke You're welcome! Consider pressing the checkbox next to one of the answers to mark your question as solved.

Comment: What’s the point of forwarding the callable before calling like this `std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a)...);` ?

Comment: @mahush A callable class can have a `&&`-qualified `operator()` (either can't be called as an lvalue at all, or has a separate `&`-qualified overload for lvalues with a different behavior). This is rare, but not unthinkable. For example, the lvalue version could copy the class state somewhere, while the rvalue version would move it.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename F, 
      typename... A, 
      typename R = std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<A>...>>
R foo(const F& aF, const A& ...aA)
```

this asks if an `F` rvalue can be called with `A` rvalues.

You aren't going to try this.  What you are going to try is this:

```
      typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F const&, A const&...>>
```

If you do this change, the code now [properly fails to compile in the 2nd case](https://godbolt.org/z/3bfb5GW8a), where you try to call a `bool&` argument with a `bool const&` argument.

If you want the 2nd case to also work, you can't take the `bool` by `const&` and then pass it to a lambda that expects a `bool&`.

```
template <typename F, 
      typename... A, 
      typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F const&, A&&...>>
R foo(const F& aF, A&& ...aA)

{
  return aF(std::forward<A>(aA)...);
}
```

and now [both test cases compile](https://godbolt.org/z/5YYbWq56o).